# simple django: what is wrong with this code?

Tags: django

i have this code:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.account' %}">Account</a></li>
```

and when i run it i get an error about how it is gibberish. The error doesn't say that, of course, it says:

> Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.account' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

This is only for the "account" option, the "logout" option works fine on its own.
Naturally i searched SO for the error, and it is something about how the "account" doesn't exist anywhere - but I am super new to django and have no idea how to fix!

So, assuming i wanted that line above to work - and by work i mean present as a link to some page (it doesn't matter what, of course, but as it happens it would show the user's details ~ username, option to alter password etc) what do i need to do?

Do i need something in my urls.py? Something in my forms?

UPDATE
ok, so given that the {% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.XYZ' %} points to the member of the views class that is called XYZ, if I wanted to add an "accounts" page, would i subclass the views class and add the functionality in there?
Or would i be saner just adding a new view ('/accounts/') and adding in the view stuff that way?

cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That function/view (`account`) does not exist. Take a look at the code:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py

Of course that a view that does not exist can't be reversed. What are you trying to do?

**Answering what you asked in your comment (it's other question BTW)**

You should create your own view. Views in Django are functions, so you can't "subclass" them. You could reuse and combine though.

I was going to show you how to do it, but it's better to point you to the right location. Start with the django tutorial:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/

In an hour you'll understand the whole process.

As a final note, you can find third party applications that handle user accounts data, you could take a look at [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com), but I recommend you to do it by yourself. You'll learn a lot in the process.

Comment: ohhhhhhh. so it is linking to a predefined function. got. it. so, if i wanted to have a view that allowed the user to see their username/password/email and provide options to edit them, would i need to subclass that view and provide an account method?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the documentation about how URLs work in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/

Comment: ok, i've read it - and i am still unsure. Updated the question!

Comment: There are pre-defined forms and views within auth that will help you let someone change their username, password, etc.